# Flask-Security AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-security

I'm working on a computer grid dashboard and ran into the following error a few times:

```sh
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'
```

This happens after I change my model a little bit.
The original model is:

```py
class Worker (UserMixin, Base):

  __tablename__ = 'worker'

  ...
```

and when it's exactly like this I get the following:

```sh
[2020-03-13 15:10:11,389] ERROR in app: Exception on /admin/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1947, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2241, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_principal.py", line 477, in _on_before_request
    identity = loader()
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 245, in _identity_loader
    if not isinstance(current_user._get_current_object(), AnonymousUserMixin):
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 335, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 359, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 321, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 221, in _user_loader
    return _security.datastore.find_user(id=user_id)
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/datastore.py", line 254, in find_user
    return self.user_model.query.filter_by(**kwargs).first()
AttributeError: type object 'Worker' has no attribute 'query'
```

Looking for this error on the Internet, I get the answer that it should inherit also from `db.Model`, being `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`. But then I'd create an "import loop", once I'd need to import `Worker` to app from models, and `db` to models from app. This obviously crashes.

A workaround I thought would work was to import the Model object like

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import Model
```

and make my model inherit from it

```py
class Worker (Model, UserMixin, Base):
  ...
```

but finally I get the following:

```sh
[2020-03-13 15:06:45,878] ERROR in app: Exception on /admin/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1947, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2241, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_principal.py", line 477, in _on_before_request
    identity = loader()
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 245, in _identity_loader
    if not isinstance(current_user._get_current_object(), AnonymousUserMixin):
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 335, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 359, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 321, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 221, in _user_loader
    return _security.datastore.find_user(id=user_id)
  File "/home/rancher/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_security/datastore.py", line 254, in find_user
    return self.user_model.query.filter_by(**kwargs).first()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'
```

How can I make this right? I'm just furious about it and can't focus anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has driven me crazy at times as well.

In your model file:
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Worker(db.Model, UserMixin) (not sure what Base is)

Then in your app file:

from worker import db

db.init_app(app)

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, but now I face another issue:

```sh

sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'roles_workers.role_id' could not find table 'role' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

```

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Worker(db.Model,UserMixin, Base):
    ...
```

Comment: That's the thing. The `app` and `Worker` are in different files

Comment: you need to import it.

Comment: I don't think you really get it. If i do import it on both files, it creates an import loop